# Ubuntu installation is not showing hard disk partitions properly

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

The hard disk partition table is not showing properly, in Windows I have C partition and two other partitions and a 100 GB free space ready for Linux .

Any help ?

Disk partitions as shown in the installer:

[image: img]

Disk partitions as shown using lsblk (Shows it like Windows):

[image: img]

Output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print`:

[image: img]

Comment: So you're missing `/dev/sda5` in the Ubuntu installer? What is the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print`?

Comment: Not just that the installer has 800 GB partition and 100 GB one and a 0.5 GB one and  1MB one , i don't know what are these , "sudo parted /dev/sda print" show this 
http://i.imgur.com/j7H7joT.png